# Swift randomizer with variables

Tags: swift, variables, random, integer, var

I have two `String` Type values as `Int` number.
I like to randomize between these two.

With this code:

```
let random = Int.random(in: myvar1...myvar2)
```

it does not work. How can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe `[myvar1, myvar2].randomElement()`?

Comment: What exactly does “it won’t work” mean? Compile time error? Runtime crash? Undesired behaviour? Without details, there’s not much we can do

Comment: I mean a random number between my two variables. Example: myvar1 is 9 and myvar2 20 and the randomizer is normally like this: Int.random(in: 9…20) but with variables it doesnt work.

Comment: Thx it worked i forgot the Int after myvar1(myvar2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your variables look like this?

```
let myvar1: String = "1"
let myvar2: String = "10"
```

Those are both `String`s, so `myvar1...myvar2` becomes a range of `String`.

However, the [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random) method takes in a range of `Int`, so you'll first need to convert them to `Int`s.

```
if let myvar1Int = Int(myvar1), let myvar2Int = Int(myvar2) {

    let random = Int.random(in: myvar1Int...myvar2Int)

    print(random) /// Result: 6

}
```

Comment: i wrote that code into my app and i get this error:
Error Cannot use instance member 'myvar1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
Error Cannot use instance member 'myvar2' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
Can you help?

Comment: @Konsti_x08 so in Xcode, you can only have executable swift code inside a function. You can't have it directly within a class, such as `class ViewController: UIViewController { ... CAN'T GO HERE! ...}`.